# How to display dynamically generated pdf files in the browser, tomcat server, java webapp

Tags: java, pdf, browser

I am creating a dynamic web application in Java using Eclipse. My web application basically creates PDF files by getting information from IOS app.

After creating PDFs, I want to show it inside the IOS app. I saved the generated PDF files dynamically into the `WebContent` directory of the Eclipse project.

In order to test in `localhost` that I can display PDF files in my IOS app, the app needs to know the URL of the PDF file.

However, the Tomcat server cannot display the PDF file in the browser. So how do I display the generated PDF files in the browser first? Do i need to do a servlet mapping which would be difficult as the PDF files are generated dynamically.

[Here is my directory to store pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIihb.png)

[Another Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7pBi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Tomcat server isn't going to display static resources (*.jpg, *.png, *.pdf etc) automatically unless it's been instructed to do so. In order to have Tomcat retrieve those resources, add the following to your web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>   
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.pdf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Note that you're using a `default` servlet and not your custom servlet that handles dynamic content.

This example assumes that you store your PDFs to the file system (in a folder accessible to your web app). Just because they're created on-the-fly (dynamically) doesn't matter as long as you return an URL to the generated file.

UPDATE:
Your servlet should return the URL to your PDF file, e.g

http://localhost:8080/data/img/012725.pdf

Now, when you click that link (either in the browser or your iOS app), the PDF will be downloaded to your client.

Comment: Hi, sorry, I don't actually get your answer. How do I access pdf in the browser using default servlet. I edited my question to show my directory for pdf. What do you mean by "return an URL to the generated file"? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: The default servlet is just Tomcat's default servlet, it's not something you should worry about, just include that in your web.xml

Comment: I wonder, will it work the same way if I deploy it on actual server? like digital ocean droplet?

Comment: Absolutely, it should make no difference.

Comment: Hi, Sir, I'm hitting another problem. I edited my question with screenshot below. The problem is that when i generate pdf on the fly, the eclipse ide doesn't reflect real time changes. Inside the finder, I can see the newly generated pdf, however inside the eclipse I cannot see that pdf (screenshot). As a result, I cannot display it on the browser. However if i refresh the project folder in the eclipse, only then it shows up the pdf. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Your application (when it's deployed) will normally run outside  Eclipse and then you won't get  -404 error.